# How do Login programmatically gmail using Oauth 2

Tags: android, gmail, oauth-2.0

I am new to Android, I want to Login Gmail without entering user ID and password manually. i search lot but still i am unable to do it. please help me. i would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below steps are require to login to Google.

go to this link [Oauth 2.0]:[How to send mail programmatically in android using OAuth2.0 token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521956/how-to-send-mail-programmatically-in-android-using-oauth2-0-token/18916265#18916265)

Comment: thanks @IPL its working. now i am able to login gmail using Oauth 2.0.